# Wifi Jammer SH1106Wire.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arduino-esp8266

Trying to upload code onto esp8266 module for a wifi jammer.  [I followed these instructions](https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Wifi-Jammer-With-ESP8266-and-Mobile-App)/

When uploading the code I keep getting the error message SH1106Wire.h: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/spacehuhn/esp8266_deauther/wiki/Installation#compiling-using-arduino-ide and https://github.com/spacehuhn/esp8266_deauther/issues/764 for ensuring all SDK files are available.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been stuck on this for a while and the information you sent me helped me a lot. You're the best and thanks again for your help.

Comment: @FrancoLopez, welcome to StackOverflow. You can click the tick/check-mark next to the best answer to your question, marking it as a solution. When you get enough reputation, you can click the up-arrow to upvote answers, questions and comments.